# How to create modeling tool in html5

Tags: javascript, html, gojs

A diagram tool in html 5 with drag and drop functionality including the connectors.

consider a drawing tool with rectangle circle and a data store getting connected through arrows on mouse clicks and then generating a XML file for the same.

Comment: There's no question here. You should try things yourself and post here when you require help with your implementations.

Comment: There is a question, but not that obvious. He is asking about techs to use for such purposes.

Comment: This is not a proper question. Please see how to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't know what the question really is, either, but since the questioner knows about GoJS, http://gojs.net, I suggest starting with one of the samples at http://gojs.net/samples that seems closest to what they want.

Comment: What did you do in the end?

Comment: i used mxgraph js for my implementation

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), which specification is accessible [here](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/); along with [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) & [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

[EDIT]

Why not [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Canvas) & its [2D API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/)? Because the export to (png, ...) is not as efficient and powerful as [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). After all, it's just a modeling tool

Answer (score 0):

The OP may want to try gojs.

gojs is a sophisticated JavaScript library for drawing diagrams utilising the html canvas, available from http://www.nwoods.com/products/gojs/. It is not a 'free' product but there is a free-to-use trial version that is fully functional save for displaying a watermark on the diagram.

It abstracts from primitive drawing operations to a much higher level and offers many diagram type (org charts, flow diagrams, etc, etc) that are quick to create and live rather than simply being drawings. It uses a model-view approach to diagramming which is very productive. It supports drag and drop within diagrams and from a palette of components.

Their support is good too.

I have no relationship to the vendor, other than being a happy customer.

Comment: Why the downvote please ? I have described a solution to the OP's rather vague question. If you know gojs then you will know it is a viable option. I have personal experience after conducting a thorough trawl of similar tools and have enjoyed excellent support from the vendor. Explain please.

Comment: Regarding suggestions to use SVG, you should consider the balance of effort between learning how to draw with primitive line, point and curves then how to collate into a diagram (SVG way), versus concentrating on delivering the diagram you require (the library way).

Comment: To re-state the previous comment more clearly, learning SVG primitives in order to produce a diagram with sophisticated functionality is like learning about engineering so that you can build your own car and drive it somewhere. For a select few learning SVG may be useful. For the majority knowing about SVG may be of some overall use but will be of little usable value.  In practical terms, if you build it yourself, you will spend so long fixing bugs in your home-grown diagram tool that you will never achieve the goal and your boss should fire you for wasting time.